# Can you burn custom tokens on the Stellar network?

Tags: token

I'm curious if the Stellar network has the ability to "burn" or "freeze" custom tokens created on the network.

The two use cases would be:

1. Token is assigned to an account and should be frozen and not be assignable again to another account.
2. Token is removed from the network completely and cannot be assigned to another account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To freeze a custom asset you can send it to the other account and remove signers of the destination account (set master weight to `0`).

To burn a custom asset so it's not taken into account when calculating a circulating supply you can send it back to the issuer account of the asset.

Answer (score 2):

Freezing Assets can also be done by revoke authorization, if you are the issuer and not in control over the account holding the asset .. read the chapter
Requiring or Revoking Authorization

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html