# How to burn tokens with unlimited supply in Stellar?

Tags: assets, smart-contract

I can see a similar question [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/492/can-you-burn-custom-tokens-on-the-stellar-network). The accepted answer suggests:

> To burn a custom asset so it's not taken into account when calculating
>   a circulating supply you can send it back to the issuer account of the
>   asset.

But in case of unlimited supply tokens, we can't set master key weight of issuing address to zero (since it needs to create more tokens). So if we sent tokens to be burned to issuing address back, the issuing address can re-spend tokens and hence tokens are not burned at all.

The other possible option is to have a separate account whose master key weight is 0 and send the tokens (assets) to be burned to that address. But then this will be counted while calculating the current circulation of tokens?

Is there an optimal method to burn tokens with the unlimited supply in Stellar blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

Removing assets from supply is done by sending it back to the issuing account, just as you quoted.

If your supply is unlimited or not doesn't matter, removed assets gets removed.
If you have an issue with the assets being able to re-issue new assets, then *that* is your problem, and you shouldn't have an uncapped supply.

Comment: Thanks for Anser:), but What is actually meant by "You should not have an uncapped supply". This may be the basic requirement of a project to have an uncapped supply. There is a difference in issuing token and sending tokens to issuer. When we issue from issuer account, its balance is always 0. but if we send token to it ( for burn), it's balance is increased. So ideally this not "burning", this is just a transfer and issuer can transfer burn tokens to someone else.

Comment: If you burn an amount of an asset, that amount can be re-issued again, because your account doesn't have its supply *restricted*. That account can issue assets any time it wants, and it has *nothing* to do with burning.

You are confusing different concepts. You're talking about burning, but it seems like your issue is with the unlimited supply.

You can create a locked account you send burnt assets to, but the issuer will be able to re-issue them.

If you send assets back to the the issuer the balance is still 0, because an issuer can't hold its own assets.